# Why compilation error in a for comprehension and pattern matching for case classes

Tags: scala

Could anyone know why the following code cannot pass compilation? I just don't know why the type mismatch happens.

The output should look like this:

```
List(Book, DVD, MP3)
```

My code:

```
package library3 {

  abstract class Item() {
    def use(): Unit
  }

  // match on Items.

  case class Book (val title: String) extends Item
  case class DVD (val title: String) extends Item
  case class MP3 (val title: String) extends Item
}

object Ch3_2 {

  import library3._

  def main( args:Array[String] ) = {
    val items = List( new Book( "The Hobbit" ),
              new DVD( "Black Adder Goes Forth" ),
              new MP3( "Watership Down" )
            )

    println( classifyItems( items ) )
  }

  def classifyItems( items:List[Item] ): List[String] = {

    // Use a for comprehension and pattern matching to take a list of
    // items and return a list of types of items.

    for (item <- items) { // <=== type mismatch;
        item match {
            case b: Book => println("Book")
            case d: DVD => println("DVD")
            case m: MP3 => println("MP3")
        }
    }

  }

}
```

The error message:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Unit
 required: List[String]
    for (item <- items) {
              ^
one error found
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working version of your code:

```
abstract class Item

case class Book (title: String) extends Item
case class DVD (title: String) extends Item
case class MP3 (title: String) extends Item

val items = List( 
  Book( "The Hobbit" ),
  DVD( "Black Adder Goes Forth" ),
  MP3( "Watership Down" )
)

def classifyItems(items:List[Item]): List[String] = 
  for (item <- items) yield
    item match {
      case b: Book => "Book"
      case d: DVD => "DVD"
      case m: MP3 => "MP3"
      case _ => "else"
    }
```

Verification that it actually works:

```
scala> classifyItems(items)
res2: List[String] = List(Book, DVD, MP3)
```

A few remarks:

- When using case class you don't have to use `new`
- You have to use the `yield` statement after the `for` statement.
- If you don't want to use a default case in the `match`, the you have to use a `sealed trait` or a `sealed class`
- More info about the `for` statement in Scala: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/111

Comment: Thanks. I know your verification is correct. but when I do compile, it won't work.
//////////
scalac yourcode.scala
/////////

yourcode.scala:9: error: expected class or object definition
val items = List(
^
yourcode.scala:15: error: expected class or object definition

def classifyItems(items:List[Item]): List[String] =

^
two errors found

Comment: I tested my code in the REPL, so you have to put it in a class or an object before testing it. For example: `object Ch3_2{val items... ; def classifyItems ...}`

Comment: Thank you. You code is perfect. I know my error happens because I did not define use() in derived classes as the same as use() in the base class Item.

Comment: Yes, I had to remove the part about `use()` because it was not implemented in your piece of code. You are welcome.

Comment: If you make `Item` a `sealed class` you do not need to check in the pattern match against a default value.

Comment: This is what I wanted to say when I said: "If you don't want to use an escape case in the match, the you have to use a sealed trait or class" - I edited my answer hoping it is more clear.